# Load image in local HTML file -- UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, uiwebview

I load a local HTML file in a UIWebView like so:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

In my index.html, how do I load a display a local image (added to project through Xcode) with img src="..."/> ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of loading with an `NSURLRequest`, read the html file into an `NSString` and create an `NSURL` to the directory with image files.

Then use UIWebView's `- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL` method.

So, you'd have something like...

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
```

Comment: What if we load the html from the Documents, not from the Bundle?