# Load local images in a local HTML file within a UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have tried a lot of other answers on here, but I can't seem to figure this one out. I have a local HTML file that embeds some local images.

My folder structure is:

```
assets
>html
>>*.html
>>*.html
>>*.html
>media
>>*.jpeg
>>*.jpeg
>>*.jpeg
```

and I request the images from the HTML with

```
<img src="../media/sjolyst.jpg" alt="Sjølyst"/>
```

My code for loading the web view pretty simple,

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(htmlFileName, ofType: "html")!
let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!
var html = NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

detailWebView.loadHTMLString(html as! String, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

This seems to be the same as all the answers I've seen on SO. Still, it renders like this:
[image: :(]
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147747/load-image-in-local-html-file-uiwebview). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is,

**Your app can't figure out the where your resources are, and where your html is.**

**Why?** Because your html and resources are added in bundle, which is scattered. You need to put all in single folder, so that your resources are accessible. According to your code

```
<img src="../media/sjolyst.jpg" alt="Sjølyst"/>
```

You are trying to fetch the image relatively, but in actual folder structure there is no `../media`.

**Solution** simple.

1. Delete all your html thing, I guess the folder.
2. Re-add the HTML folder, see image
   [image]
3. You should see a folder like image below

   [image]

You are now good to go.

By adding a folder mentioned **in 2.** creates a folder in bundle path, and put all the resource with correct folder structure inside it.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Quick and easy solution :)